# Postfix catch all overrides all other patterns in virtual_alias_maps

Tags: postfix

I think i have checked every thread with 'catch all' and 'overrides catch all' with Postfix but still can get any solution for my problem.
I got an incoming(only) smtp server `Postfix version 3.5.8`. I would like to make it an open relay and I'm able to achieve it with `virtual_alias_domains=static:yes` in `/etc/postfix/main.cf`. Then i would like to dispatch these messages to few users depending on recipients domain so i have created some patterns with pcre in `virtual_alias_maps = pcre:/etc/postfix/virtual`:

```
/1@test/ test
/2@test/ test2
/@test/ catchallfromtest
/@/ catchall
```

with `/etc/postfix/aliases`

```
test: "/var/mail/test.mail"
test2: "/var/mail/test2.mail"
catchallfromtest: "/var/mail/catchallfromtest.mail"
catchall: "/var/mail/catchall.mail"
```

If i would comment out  `/@/ catchall` email would be dispatched correctly  but without that every email goes to catchall. I have tried many ideas (different order, split it to separated files, with different db types, with `virtual_alias_map` for some users and with recipient_bcc_maps for catchall, with `luser_relay` but it works only for `$mydomain` so it won't work for my case, with exclusion in pattern and in row (`!//`)) and with different form of catchall (`//`,`/.*@.*/`,`/^.*@.*&/`,`/.+@.+/` etc). When i try to test it with

```
postmap -q "1@test" pcre:/etc/postfix/virtual
```

it returns the correct alias but when i try send email it goes to catchall. What can i else try?  From [documentation][1]

```
Patterns are applied in the order as specified in the  table,  until  a pattern is found that matches the input string.
```

So it should stop just after the first pattern match but it doesn't.
[1]: http://www.postfix.org/pcre_table.5.html